# jQuery validate plugin with data-encrypted-name attribute for Braintree

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, braintree

I am implementing a form of Braintree (payment gateway) which requires the fields of credit card have the following attribute: **data-encrypted-name**

This is my form:

```
<form id="braintree-payment-form">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
    <br/>    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="number" data-encrypted-name="number" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="cvv" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that in trying to validate these fields using jQuery Validate, the validation does not work correctly.

This is my code (including qtip library to show error messages):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#braintree-payment-form").validate({

        errorClass: "errormessage",
        errorClass: 'error',
        validClass: 'valid',
        rules: {
          "first_name": { required: true, maxlength: 45 },
          "last_name": { required: true, maxlength: 45 }                                          
          },
        messages: { 
          "first_name":       { required: "Enter your Name", maxlength: "Largo máximo de 45 caracteres" },
          "last_name":       { required: "Enter your Last Name", maxlength: "Largo máximo de 45 caracteres" }                                       
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element)
        {
          //qtip
          var elem = $(element),
            corners = ['right center', 'left center'],
            flipIt = elem.parents('span.right').length > 0;

          if(!error.is(':empty')) {
            elem.filter(':not(.valid)').qtip({
              overwrite: false,
              content: error,
              position: {
                my: corners[ flipIt ? 0 : 1 ],
                at: corners[ flipIt ? 1 : 0 ],
                viewport: $(window)
              },
              show: {
                event: false,
                ready: true
              },
              hide: false,
              style: {
                classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue'
              }
            })
            .qtip('option', 'content.text', error);
          }
          else { elem.qtip('destroy'); }
        },
        success: $.noop,
        debug: false
      });

$( "#number" ).rules( "add", {
        required: true,
    creditcard: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Credit Card Number is required",
        creditcard: "Invalid Credit Card Number"
  }
});

$( "#cvv" ).rules( "add", {
required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "CVV Invalid"
  }
});

  });
```

The first and last name are validated correctly, but if you enter the card number, the first number is validated and then the CVV field repeats the same message validation card.

Look at this link: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nachosarmiento/9j6FU/)

My code is based on the example from this answer: [jQuery validate plugin adding multiple .rules() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458005/jquery-validate-plugin-adding-multiple-rules-function)

Thanks in advance!

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jQuery validate plugin requires your inputs to have `name` attributes in order to function properly.

```
<form id="braintree-payment-form">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" data-encrypted-name="number" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="cvv" id="cvv" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

However, the encryption methods inside of braintree.js will remove the `name` attribute of inputs that it encrypts to prevent you from submitting raw credit card data through to your server. This may cause issues if you encrypt the form, but input validation fails. Typically, we'd recommend you perform the encryption as the last step of the form submission process.

Comment: @Shina validation without name attributes not working for me. I want validation with c#.net

Comment: <form id="braintree-payment-form">
   <div>Number:<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" placeholder="Number" />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Number)</div>
    <div>CVV:<input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" placeholder="CVV" />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CVV)</div>               
 <div>CardHolderName: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardHolderName, new { @placeholder = "Card Holder Name" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CardHolderName)</div>                       
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: @Shina Sorry I am new here at stackoverflow So I am unable to paste my code as html

Comment: @KulbirSingh ... do you have attribute: required="required" ?

Comment: @Shina thanks very much for your kind reply, yes i have required attribute for both CVV and number but strange behavior is that required attribute working fine for "Number" field but not for "CVV" field. When I am try to submit the form with empty CVV field it allows form submission. I am unable to catch the issue

Comment: @KulbirSingh ... I think I had that problem. Do this: <input type="number" name="cvv" size="5" class="form-control input-lg cvvRequired" autocomplete="off" placeholder="024" required> and then do something like this in your JS if($(this).valid()) { $('.cvvRequired').removeAttr('type').attr('data-encrypted-name', 'cvv');" once the form as been submitted.

Comment: @Shina thanks, Sure I will try, do you think data-encrypted-name attribute is creating problem ?